# Border assigned over TD is not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a `Table` in which there are TD's. In one of those td's, I am applying border. It is
working fine in CHROME, but its getting disturbed in **IE.**

**NOTE**:- Earlier, when the cellpadding of the table was 2 it was looking fine but when I increased the cellpadding the border got disturbed.

Here is how it looks like

[image: img1]

and here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwL3a719/)

what should I do to make it work in IE

Comment: I don't think :last-child is supported in old IE.

Comment: @HermLuna: so what should I do for that ? I mean any other way to tackle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want it looking like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/o1j88quk/3/

If so add `table { border-collapse: collapse; }` to your css.

May also have to remove `cellspacing="10"` from inline style of `table`

---

To remove middle line

change

```
tr.black-border td {
  border-top: 1px solid #0D63B0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0D63B0;
}
```

to

```
tr.black-border:nth-child(3) td {
  border-top: 1px solid #0D63B0;
}
tr.black-border:nth-child(4) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0D63B0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can control the border style by adding classes, if old IE has a problem with `nth-child(x)`

Comment: i have already added that to table, but from right it looks something like this https://s16.postimg.io/68f5w670l/image.png

Comment: I dont have IE to test it in but try removing `cellspacing="10"`

Comment: yes, now it worked. but the space between the two td's is not as it was earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure which two td's but try adjusting it using padding-left and right. I updated the fiddle with much of the styling transferred to the css pane including td padding.

Comment: the final thing, I want to remove the middle line see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xrgyvy84/ from the image here https://s10.postimg.org/u24apg06h/image.png

Comment: Updated the fiddle and my answer, let me know if thats what you meant.

Comment: added like this https://jsfiddle.net/5zyv2mk9/ but i cant see any border with this..

Comment: i want border from `Area(Hectares)  to Status`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/5zyv2mk9/1/  change your blackborder class into blackborder1 and blackborder2 and use the new css from the fiddle